# Numpy .A1 array not always present

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The following code

```
samplePoints=(rand(samples,variables)-0.5)*10
output=numpy.zeros((samples,1))
for i in range(0,samples):
    output[i,0]=eq(samplePoints[i,:].T)
print output.A1;
```

crashes at the last line with AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'A1'

The following code on the other hand

```
samplePoints=(rand(samples,variables)-0.5)*10
output=numpy.zeros((samples,1))
for i in range(0,samples):
    output[i,0]=eq(samplePoints[i,:].T)
output=output+rand(samples,1)
print output.A1;
```

does not. The only thing that was added was the +rand(sample,1). 
Why is it that not every numpy array has an A1 field ??? And how can I obtain a 1 dimensional flattened version of the array in such a way that it will work on all types of numpy arrays ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your examples are not complete, so I can't run them and reproduce the problem.  Apparently the example that crashes creates a regular numpy array, which does not have the `A1` attribute, while the example that works creates a numpy [`matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).  The [`A1` attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html) of a matrix returns a flattened numpy array.

Instead of using the `output.A1`, you can write `np.ravel(output)`.  That should work for a regular numpy array and a numpy matrix.